# Triggering test execution on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a question regarding test automation with Jenkins. I'd like to know how to trigger test execution when application under test (AUT) is built each time. I want to understand how to link running my tests with UAT build. Because my test framework and UAT are two different applications. I know how to trigger build of my test framework. But I don't know how to automatically start running my tests when UAT is built. I'm new in test automation and my question may sound inappropriate, or I may be missing something. Thanks in advance.